# Get rows from db within the week of NOW()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to select all rows from the database where the rows date (deadline_date) is within the current week and `deadline_date >= NOW()`. The whole goal is to show the user projects that are expiring within this week.

Not sure how to structure my query, any advice or links?

fyi, **deadline_date format = 2013-12-10 00:00:00**

**Current query:**

```
$query = "SELECT short_name, description, priority
          FROM tasks 
          WHERE client_id = '$client_id'
          AND deadline_date >= NOW()";
```

Comment: I suggest that you use php code to generate start and end date variables.  Then have where deadline_date >= $startDate and deadline_date < the day after $endDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `BETWEEN` might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks man. I wrote this up `deadline_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `WEEK(date)` of mysql.

```
SELECT a FROM t WHERE WEEK(deadline_date) = WEEK(NOW())
```

Comment: Using functions like that tends to be slow.

Comment: I made my suggestion in a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT 
    short_name, 
    description, 
    priority
FROM tasks 
WHERE client_id = '$client_id'
AND deadline_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you

for  [Mysql date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

and to find day of week in php

```
$dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($date));
$result    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(($day - $dayofweek).' day', strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: It's always better to run this in a query when you can. If I knew it wasn't possible, I'd result to this method.

Comment: I disagree.  I think that application code is well suited for generating variables.

Comment: A difference in opinions proves we can both form one.